# Lots of connection logs after open ports of k8s service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Im now using aws k8s service (eks). deployments and Loadbalancer Services were used.

(2 nodes, 1 loadbalancer service, 1 deployment, 1 pod, 1 replicaset was used.)

However, when I add a port to the service, so many connections are being connected to the port I opened.
Log looks like as below.

```
[17:12:21.843] Client Connected [/192.168.179.222:28607]
[17:12:21.843] Client Disconnected [/192.168.179.222:28607]
[17:12:21.864] Client Connected [/192.168.179.222:16888]
[17:12:21.864] Client Disconnected [/192.168.179.222:16888]
[17:12:21.870] Client Connected [/192.168.79.91:58902]
[17:12:21.870] Client Disconnected [/192.168.79.91:58902]
[17:12:22.000] Client Connected [/192.168.179.222:52060]
[17:12:22.000] Client Disconnected [/192.168.179.222:52060]
[17:12:23.118] Client Connected [/192.168.79.91:14650]
[17:12:23.119] Client Disconnected [/192.168.79.91:14650]
```

192.168.179.222 and 192.168.79.91 are my nodes' IPs and logs are from pods.

I thought it is because of health check of aws loadbalancer, but health check interval is 30sec and it doesn't make sense.
Since lots of logs, i cannot see my real transaction logs.

How can I get rid of those connections? What is the reason of those logs?

--- add

```
NAME                                                 STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION                INTERNAL-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      OS-IMAGE         KERNEL-VERSION                  CONTAINER-RUNTIME
ip-192-168-179-222.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   11d   v1.16.12-eks-904af05   192.168.179.222   ##########   Amazon Linux 2   4.14.181-142.260.amzn2.x86_64   docker://19.3.6
ip-192-168-79-91.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal     Ready    <none>   11d   v1.16.12-eks-904af05   192.168.79.91     ##########   Amazon Linux 2   4.14.181-142.260.amzn2.x86_64   docker://19.3.6
```

these are my node info. Im probably sure that ips from log is node IP.
I have several processes in my pod, and Every processes are countered with too many connection logs.

Comment: Do you have healthchecks (readiness and liveness probes) in the deployment file?

Comment: No I do not have both of them in the deployment file. @AhmadAabed

Comment: I would guess that those are the typical scanners all over the internet trying to connect, and since you are not handling the realip of the connection you are logging the node IP which will appear because of everything going through kube-proxy

so for some reason the connection IP gets masqueraded with the node IP
for testing you can log a legit request from a know IP and you will find that it's logged as the node IP also are you sure those are the node IPs?

Comment: I added my node information. Every processes connect and disconnect with unknown client about 2 times in a second. If these are because of connection from all over the internet, how can I prevent them? @AhmadAabed

Comment: There are multiple ways to do so, 1- you can ignore them :D, 2- IP white listing,3-  Adding a WAF

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a result of scanners on the internet restlessly trying to find vulnerable applications

To fix that and to have a cleaner logs you can

1. Do IP white listing on the security group, so that certain IPs can only connect to your service
2. Install WAF to filter scanners out

Also you may want to have a structured logs, where your legit logs has a certain format that can be easily spotted and filtered away from garbage logs created by the scanner

Comment: I added my IP to k8s cluster whiteList, but It doesnt work. I think scanner is not the reason. @AhmadAabed

Comment: @YeSeulBae so your load balancer security group is allowing access to the port only for your IP?

Comment: Im sure that it is because of health check. When I remove the rule of healthcheck, the logs not appear. However, the rule registered again automatically, so I cannot remove the healthcheck rule.
Is anybody know how to remove healthcheck rule?  @Ahmad Aabed